# Posting picture to Facebook wall via POST object not appearing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a picture with publish_stream permissions from my site onto Facebook. For some reason, the picture doesn't show up when I post but everything else works fine.

By accessing http://www.mysite.com/image/questions.png, the picture shows up correctly. Am I missing something?

```
$body = array(
            'name'          => 'Join this site',
            'message'       => '',
            'description'   => 'Check this out',
            'picture'       => 'http://www.mysite.com/image/questions.png',
            'link'          => SITE_URL,
            );      
        $batchPost = array();
```

Then I batch post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check to see if it really works.

```
$body = array(
            'name'          => 'Join this site',
            'message'       => '',
            'description'   => 'Check this out',
            'picture'       => 'http://www.mysite.com/image/questions.png',
            'link'          => SITE_URL,
            );      
        $batchPost = array();
        $status = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $body); 
        if (isset($status['id'])) //Add a check
        {
            echo "Message posted to wall!";
        }
```

---

If not you can use JavaScript SDK `FB.ui` method to post to Facebook Wall. It is more flexible in my opinion as users can input their own message, unlike how it is defined by the developer through the PHP SDK method.

**JavaScript SDK FB.ui Method**

```
<script>
function postToWall()
        {
            var obj = {
              method: "feed",
              name: "Join this site",
              description: "Check this out",
              caption: "CAPTION",
              picture: "http://www.mysite.com/image/questions.png",
              link: "SITE_URL"
            };

            function callback(response) {
              //do something
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
        }
</script>
```

More on JavaScript SDK Feed Dialog: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

**Edit:** Use another image and try again. http://www.mysite.com/image/questions.png has been removed. Upload your picture on some image hosting website instead of hotlinking the image directly.

Comment: Thank you! Turned out I had a comment in there.